# mysql, @variable and if statement

Tags: mysql, variables, if-statement

guys,
I follow instruction from this [link](http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/get_top_n_each_group)

I created table like this

```
CREATE TABLE cities
(
  city VARCHAR(80),
  country VARCHAR(80),
  population INT
);

INSERT INTO cities VALUES ('New York', 'United States', 8175133); 
INSERT INTO cities VALUES ('Los Angeles', 'United States', 3792621); 
INSERT INTO cities VALUES ('Chicago', 'United States', 2695598); 

INSERT INTO cities VALUES ('Paris', 'France', 2181000);
INSERT INTO cities VALUES ('Marseille', 'France', 808000);
INSERT INTO cities VALUES ('Lyon', 'France', 422000);

INSERT INTO cities VALUES ('London', 'United Kingdom',  7825300);
INSERT INTO cities VALUES ('Birmingham', 'United Kingdom', 1016800);
INSERT INTO cities VALUES ('Leeds', 'United Kingdom', 770800);
```

when i run this query

```
SELECT city, country, population
  FROM
  (SELECT city, country, population, 
              @country_rank := IF(@current_country = country, @country_rank + 1, 1) AS country_rank,
              @current_country := country 
    FROM cities
    ORDER BY country, population DESC
   ) ranked
   WHERE country_rank <= 2;
```

it doesn't give me 2 largest cities for each country

Is there something I missed? thanks

Comment: Works for me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a5a1/1

Comment: it doesn't work for me, i checked my mysql version and it says 5.0
maybe i should upgrade to 5.6
thanks @Barmar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the below two line codes before your codes, and  it will work.

```
SET @current_country:=NULL;
SET @country_rank:=0;


SELECT city, country, population
  FROM
  (SELECT city, country, population, 
             @country_rank := IF(@current_country = country, @country_rank + 1, 1) AS country_rank,
          @current_country := country 
  FROM cities
  ORDER BY country, population DESC
   ) ranked
   WHERE country_rank <= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another subquery to initialize the variables:

```
SELECT city, country, population
FROM
    (SELECT city, country, population, 
            @country_rank := IF(@current_country = country, @country_rank + 1, 1) AS country_rank,
            @current_country := country 
    FROM cities
    ORDER BY country, population DESC
) ranked
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @country_rank := 0, $current_country := '') vars  
WHERE country_rank <= 2;
```